# sapui5 : typeERROR : i is not a constructor

Tags: sapui5

I faced a problem while establishing a navigation between views, so have you an idea about the meaning of that sentence :

> i is not a constructor

what is "i" exactly ?

[image: screenshot about "i is not a constructor"]

Comment: how about source code, a running example etc?

Comment: Are you sure the below answer really solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check location of controller and controller name in both view. xml and controller.js.

Example:

In view. xml

controller Name="logicalName.controller.ControllerName"

In controller. js
The place where you are defining controller name

return Controller. extend("logicalName.controller.ControllerName", {
}) ;